# Nginx url rewrite for restful url

Tags: rest, configuration, url-rewriting, nginx, static-files

I have a Rails web app which has static files under dynamic restful urls. For example:

```
/projects/1/attachments/some_file.xls
```

I want to setup Nginx to redirect to the static file on the server:

```
/public/attachments/1/some_file.xls
```

Where 1 is the dynamic project id.

How would the location block and rewrite statement look for the Nginx config file?

---

**UPDATE**

I marked an answer below as it answers my original question. Though rewriting my project attachment urls wasn't necessary in my case. I forgot that I was already remapping the url in my Rails view erb.

My true goal was to stop Thin from adding caching response headers to my attachment files. Ultimately, I was able to prevent this with Nginx by just adding a location for attachments like such:

```
location /attachments/ {
    expires    off;
    add_header Pragma "no-cache";
    add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store";
    access_log off; 
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple example.

```
location /project/ {
    rewrite ^/project/([0-9]+)/attachments/(.*)$ /public/attachments/$1/$2 last;
}
```

If you want more complicated rule, see the official help.

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're doing something wrong with your image/file library, as you shouldn't have to do any nginx rewrite rules for Paperclip, Dragonfly, etc to just work.  For example in Paperclip you can set the url and/or path format explicitly when you use the DSL in the Model. For Paperclip it would look like this:

```
has_attached_file :attachment,
                  :url => '/attachments/:id/:style/:basename.:extension',
                  :path => ':rails_root/public/attachments/:id/:style/:basename.:extension'
```

Then everything should get served by nginx automatically since it's in your public directory. No rewrite rule necessary.

Comment: Well, I actually forgot that the urls were already remapped manually in my View erb. What I was really trying to achieve is bypassing Thin so that I can turn of the caching-related response headers.

Comment: Also, these attachments are not images. They generated sql files, generated excel files, uploaded csv files etc. I'm not using Paperclip or attachment_fu, though I did evaluate them at the time. I'm just storing these attachments under public/attachments/:project_id and hiding that fact from the user. The user see the url projects/:project_id/file_name. No model either.

Comment: All the libraries I mentioned can handle any file types, not just images.  But, typically when I do something like what you're doing I'll create an Assets model that encapsulates all this file storing logic.

Comment: As far as bypassing Thin, anything in your public directory should get directly served from your web server (Apache, Nginx, etc) and never hit Thin. Only if a matching file isn't found for a given url would it get proxied to Thin.  And another reason to do things the "Rails way" is static assets get timestamps appended to their names through the Asset Pipeline, so you don't undesirably get the caching issues you mention.

Comment: Well, the files were getting served by Thin because I wasn't using anything else at the time. I added Nginx to the mix so that it could server the file (without caching headers) instead of Thin. It seems to work now. This conversation has been good, thanks for your comments!